# Git tags based on a pattern

Tags: regex, git, shell, tags

There are different versions of tags in our repository. Need to get a particular patterned tag only assuming there's only one occurrence of that type.
E.g

```
v1.1.0
1.0
v1.0
v0.1.0-0.20201201002611-5424ca76ab3e
v1.2.0-alpha
```

How can I get a particular which only follows v0.1.0-0.20201201002611-5424ca76ab3e

I have the regex
`v[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]-0.\d{14}-\b[0-9a-f]{12}\b`

I tried it using `git describe --match "v[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]-0.\d{14}-\b[0-9a-f]{12}\b" --abbrev=0 --tags $(git rev-list --tags)` but doesn't seem to work. Any other way I could get the tag with a specific format?

Comment: thank you. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following POSIX BRE pattern:

```sh
'v[0-9]*\(\.[0-9]*\)\{2\}-0\.[0-9]\{14\}-[0-9a-f]\{12\}'
```

where

- `v` - matches `v`
- `[0-9]*` - zero or more digits
- `\(\.[0-9]*\)\{2\}` - two repetitions of `.` and zero or more digits
- `-0\.` - a `0.` string
- `[0-9]\{14\}`  - fourteen digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[0-9a-f]\{12\}` - twelve digits or lowercase letters.